# FORALL Bulk Collect - Need to add a sequence to insert statement without using a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulk-collect

So I have a FORALL bulk collection that I am using to insert values into a table.

Usually I would use a loop for the sequence field that has to be populated.  Example would be like this........

seqno = seqno +1

.....and then I would loop through for each record it would increase by 1 as they are inserted.

```
SELECT bis_part, bis_part_org, bis_store, bis_bin, bis_lot, bis_qty
BULK COLLECT INTO V_STTK_CLTN 
FROM table1
WHERE bis_bin = 'DIRECT'
AND bis_store = p_org;


FORALL INDX IN 1 .. V_STTK_CLTN.COUNT 

  INSERT INTO table2
   (stl_part,
    stl_part_org,
    stl_trans,
    stl_store,
    stl_bin,
    stl_lot,
    stl_expqty,
    stl_phyqty,
    stl_rtype,
    stl_type,
    stl_line ) 
   VALUES
   (V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part_org,
    ctrans,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_store,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_bin,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_lot,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_qty,
    '',
    'STTK',
    'STTK',
     seqno);
```

How could I do this with a collection since I am using FORALL without a loop?

The seqno value is where i need the sequence.  Each time this is run it will insert these records into the same table but the sequence must start with one each time as it is a sequence for the collection not the whole table....make sense?

Comment: create a sequence and use it. SEQ_X.nexval? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: Is the `seqno` column an attribute of the collection from which you drive your FORALL statement? A bit more actual code would make your scenario clearer to us.

Comment: Use a sequence on the table you're inserting in to, or in 12c onward use an IDENTITY column?  *(So that the receiving table takes care of creating/managing your sequential values.)*

Comment: Hi thanks everyone for the help here......I added some code to show you what I am working with.  I was using a loop and just looping through the records but I have to use FORALL  insert now....no loops allowed.  Is this even possible?  I thought using ROWNUM in place of the variable seqno but I get this error.....ORA-00976: Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here.

Comment: Hi Kaushik Nayak I checked your answer.  Thank you for your willingness to help

Answer (score 1):

It is simple

Create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;
```

Let's say you want to insert into table `t`

```
create table t(id INT, rowname VARCHAR2(20));
```

This block will  insert some dummy rows in a `FORALL` block and will use a sequence. Instead of your loop, bulk collect into a collection from a `SELECT`  query or a `CURSOR`

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE ctype 
      IS TABLE OF t%ROWTYPE; 
    ct ctype; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT seq.NEXTVAL AS id, 
           'ROW' 
           ||LEVEL     AS rowname 
    bulk   collect INTO ct 
    FROM   dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100; 

    forall i IN ct.first..ct.last 
      INSERT INTO t 
      VALUES ct(i); 
END; 

/
```

[**Db fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d2e2e73da1736c14e62d03893ec6d60) demo

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, perhaps a sequence is the best method to meet the use-case requirement.

But to strictly answer your question on how to replicate an incrementing counter variable with a FORALL statement, you can do the following:

```
L_OFFSET := 0;

FORALL INDX IN 1 .. V_STTK_CLTN.COUNT 
  INSERT INTO table2
   (stl_part,
    stl_part_org,
    stl_trans,
    stl_store,
    stl_bin,
    stl_lot,
    stl_expqty,
    stl_phyqty,
    stl_rtype,
    stl_type,
    stl_line ) 
   VALUES
   (V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part_org,
    ctrans,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_store,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_bin,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_lot,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_qty,
    '',
    'STTK',
    'STTK',
     L_OFFSET+INDX);
```

In this manner you can set L_OFFSET to the initial offset and let the INDX increment it once for each record in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to add a number column to the record for the collection.

```
 TYPE STTK_RECORD IS RECORD(
```

BIS_PART        T1.BIS_PART%TYPE
 ,BIS_PART_ORG    T1.BIS_PART_ORG%TYPE
 ,BIS_STORE       T1.BIS_STORE%TYPE
 ,BIS_BIN         T1.BIS_BIN%TYPE
 ,BIS_LOT         T1.BIS_LOT%TYPE
 ,BIS_QTY         T1.BIS_QTY%TYPE
 ,RN              NUMBER
 );

Then I added the row_number function to my select statement for the bulk collect:

```
SELECT bis_part, bis_part_org, bis_store, bis_bin, bis_lot, bis_qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bis_store ORDER BY bis_bin desc) RN
```

BULK COLLECT INTO V_STTK_CLTN;

Finally I inserted the new column:

```
FORALL INDX IN V_STTK_CLTN.FIRST .. V_STTK_CLTN.LAST

  INSERT INTO T2
   (stl_part,
    stl_part_org,
    stl_trans,
    stl_store,
    stl_bin,
    stl_lot,
    stl_expqty,
    stl_phyqty,
    stl_rtype,
    stl_type,
    stl_line ) 
   VALUES
   (V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_part_org,
    ctrans,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_store,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_bin,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_lot,
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).bis_qty,
    '',
    'STTK',
    'STTK',
    V_STTK_CLTN(INDX).rn);
```